# How i can remove the blue border in Material React Modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using this [React Material Modal](https://material-ui.com/pt/components/modal/). In the demo examples you can see that when you open the modal, has a blue border.

There's a way to remove it?

I see in the Modal Api that haves the property `disableAutoFocus` but i'm setting "true" and my modal still have this blue border:

```
<Modal
        disableAutoFocus="true"
        aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
        className={classes.modal}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500,
        }}
      >
```

How i can remove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a class to `modal`, say `egClass` and set:

```
.egClass:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was to add `outline: none` to the Box I had *inside* the modal, not the modal itself

```html
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  popup: {
    outline: 'none',
  },
}));

<Modal open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
  <Box className={classes.popup}>
       ...
  </Box>
</Modal>
```